# Evalute the $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor n/2\right \rfloor}\cos(\frac{k\pi}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

**[NBHM_2007_PhD Screening Test_Analysis]**

> Evalute the $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\left
>  \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor}\cos(\frac{k\pi}{n}).$

If the upper limit of the sum is $n$ insted of ${\left
 \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor}$. I could use the formula $\int_{0}^{1}cos(\pi x)dx$. Here, how do I evalute the given limit? Please help me.

Comment: It should be $\int_0^{1/2}\cos(\pi x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: ok. I got it. Thank you for your help

Comment: Define $N = \frac{n}{2}$ and rewrite it (for even $n$) as $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^N \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot \frac{k}{N}\right)$